# I’ve overwritten some Windows files with a Linux installation. Is recovery an option?

Tags: windows, data-recovery, nvme

It’s about a movies' worth of footage and some other related project files, so fairly large. It was on a 1TB NVMe drive that I have installed ElementaryOS on. Was Windows 11 Home. Both 64 bit. Is there any reasonable chance that the data has not yet been overwritten, and can I recover the files?

I haven't done much with the Linux system yet, so it's probably smaller than the Windows installation was, and I am okay with destroying this install to get the data back. Not preferred, but optional.

I have a dual-boot of Fedora on a separate HDD, if that helps.

Comment: First step, don't use that disk for anything else. And do not boot **from it**. Then, you will have to look for recovery software (say `photorec`). But the most important thing is not to ever write to that disk again, until you've given up recovering the data. Each boot, each write, decreases the (already not too great) chances of recovering.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I am searching for lost partitions now… is that the right thing?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I think I was able to find the lost NTFS partition, but each time I try to write the new partition structure to disk, it says I have to reboot for changes to take effect, which I do, and nothing happens.

Comment: It's hard to say. And this place is more for focused questions/issues that might have a definite answer. Walkthroughs, howtos, etc. are explicitely off-topic... You're going to have to research into recovery and forensic software or try to get more professional help. As stated above, do not write to disk, unless you are like 100% sure you're not making things worse.

Comment: There is no reasonable chance that all "movies worth" (say 1GB) of files are going to be available. Although this is only 0.1% of the disk, just creating the filesystem(s) on the drive will have sprayed data over all the disk. There is a good chance that some of the data will be recoverable. So at this point you need to ask "is some data better than no data?"  and if so "what am I prepared to invest (typically time rather than money) to get this data?". At the very least I suggest you ensure you have 2TB of extra storage and **make a copy of the disk before you attempt any more "recovery"**.